# How to show autocomplete options using bootstrap typeahead only when user enters a particular character like @?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have a textarea where the user enters a lot of text. Now as soon as the user types @ (after entering his other text), I want to show him options (say various colors), and the user should be able to choose from those option.

For example, in the textarea user enters, "I bought a shirt " and then mentions @. So autocomplete option should come and he should be able to choose between Red, Blue, Green, Yellow and so on.  As soon as the user chooses any color. The total input the text area should become - " I bought a shirt @blue"

I looked at the typeahead api and couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead expects a datum with a value and tokens property.

The `token` is what is searched for when a user types, the `value` is what is displayed in the autocomplete hint and once you select it from the list.

If you give it a string, the string is changed into a datum.

If the string is just 1 word i.e. `@red` then the tokens and value will both be `@red`.
Like this:

```
{ 
    value: "@red", 
    tokens: ["@red"]
}
```

If the string is several words i.e. `I bought a shirt @red` then it is split by the spaces into multiple tokens, like this:

```
{
    value: "I bought a shirt @red",
    tokens: ["I","bought","a","shirt","@red"]
}
```

When you type into the typeahead input and you have multiple tokens, then the value can be found by typing the start of one of those tokens, i.e. typing `b` or `s` will still show `I bought a shirt @red` in the list.

I think you can get close to what you want by reviewing the below example where I have specified the first token instead of letting typeahead do it for me, this is just to give you an example of how both ways work.

You might want to think about changing how typeahead works any further because you are trying to use autocomplete in a way that probably isn't that intuitive to a user.

**see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KWftZ/2/**

html:

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
```

js:

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({                                                                                         
    local: [{
        value: 'I bought a shirt @red',
        tokens: ['@red']
    }, "@blue", "@green", "@yellow"]                                                                 
});
```